# Java Map with List value to list using streams?

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to rewrite the method below using streams but I am not sure what the best approach is? If I use `flatMap` on the values of the `entrySet()`, I lose the reference to the current key.

```
private List<String> asList(final Map<String, List<String>> map) {
    final List<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    for (final Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      final List<String> values = entry.getValue();
      values.forEach(value -> result.add(String.format("%s-%s", entry.getKey(), value)));
    }
    return result;
}
```

The best I managed to do is the following:

```
return map.keySet().stream()
          .flatMap(key -> map.get(key).stream()
                             .map(value -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(key, value)))
          .map(e -> String.format("%s-%s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Is there a simpler way without resorting to creating new `Entry` objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stream is a sequence of values (possibly unordered / parallel). `map()` is what you use when you want to map a single value in the sequence to some single other value. Say, map "alturkovic" to "ALTURKOVIC". `flatMap()` is what you use when you want to map a single value in the sequence to 0, 1, or many other values. Hence why a flatMap lambda needs to turn a value into a stream of values. flatMap can thus be used to take, say, a list of lists of string, and turn that into a stream of just strings.

Here, you want to map a single entry from your map (a single key/value pair) into a single element (a string describing it). 1 value to 1 value. That means **flatMap is not appropriate**. You're looking for just map.

Furthermore, you need both key and value to perform your mapping op, so, **keySet() is also not appropriate**. You're looking for `entrySet()`, which gives you a set of all k/v pairs, juts what we need.

That gets us to:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
   .map(e -> String.format("%s-%s", e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Your original code makes no effort to treat a single value from a map (which is a `List<String>`) as separate values; you just call `.toString()` on the entire ordeal, and be done with it. This means the produced string looks like, say, `[Hello, World]` given a map value of `List.of("Hello", "World")`. If you don't want this, you still don't want flatmap, because streams are also homogenous - the values in a stream are all of the same kind, and thus a stream of 'key1 value1 value2 key2 valueA valueB' is not what you'd want:

```
map.entrySet().stream()
   .map(e -> String.format("%s-%s", e.getKey(), myPrint(e.getValue())))
   .collect(Collectors.toList());

public static String myPrint(List<String> in) {
   // write your own algorithm here
}
```

Stream API just isn't the right tool to replace that myPrint method.

A third alternative is that you want to smear out the map; you want each string in a mapvalue's `List<String>` to first be matched with the key (so that's re-stating that key rather a lot), and then do something to that. **NOW** flatMap **IS** appropriate - you want a stream of k/v pairs first, and then do something to that, and each element is now of the same kind. You want to turn the map:

```
key1 = [value1, value2]
key2 = [value3, value4]
```

first into a stream:

```
key1:value1
key1:value2
key2:value3
key2:value4
```

and take it from there. This explodes a single k/v entry in your map into more than one, thus, flatmapping needed:

```
return map.entrySet().stream()
    .flatMap(e -> e.getValue().stream()
      .map(v -> String.format("%s-%s", e.getKey(), v))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Going inside-out, it maps a single entry within a list that belongs to a single k/v pair into the string `Key-SingleItemFromItsList`.

Comment: Amazing answer. I am not sure just about this statement: "Your original code makes no effort to treat a single value from a map (which is a List<String>) as separate values"

The original code has a double loop iterating through single values without streams. The other example is also using both `flatMap` and `map` but inefficiently using `map.get(key)` instead of using `entrySet()`. Am I missing something there? What I was missing is the idea of using `entrySet()` and a combination of `e.getKey()` and a single value using `map`. Thank you very much!

Comment: _The original code has a double loop iterating through single values without streams._ - Yes, it does, my casual glance missed the use of `.forEach`. The third example, flatmapping into `key1:value1`, `key1:value2`, etc, most closely matches the intent of your code. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

Adding my two cents to excellent answer by @rzwitserloot. Already flatmap and map is explained in his answer.

```
List<String> resultLists =  myMap.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(mapEntry -> printEntries(mapEntry.getKey(),mapEntry.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
System.out.println(resultLists);
```

Splitting this to a separate method gives good readability IMO,

```
private static Stream<String> printEntries(String key, List<String> values) {
    return values.stream().map(val -> String.format("%s-%s",key,val));
  }
```